# Is there fall foliage in Catskills first weekend in October?

Tags: hiking

I am trying to find hiking in upstate NY that will have fall foliage this weekend (Oct 1-3). Will the Catskills have good fall foliage this time of year or is there a better place to go to in the area?

Comment: this site may help: https://www.iloveny.com/things-to-do/fall/foliage-report/#accordion-target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, If you want to enjoy this year's fall foliage at Catskills then it would be great if you visit there till the middle of October, Like every year there were great fall foliage between September to October. This period of time leaves start to turn green to yellow, orange, and red. and make beautiful fall foliage.  The advantage of visiting Catskills is Hudson Vally, and your hiking purpose fulfills there because of the hiking trails and mountains.

Finger Lakes is also the best option to visit and enjoy the fall foliage.

Comment: Between September and October? That is a very short time at midnight! Can you please expand your answer with how you have this knowledge and where OP can find more details?